# Homogeneous representation of the line passing through the points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, euclidean-algorithm, homogeneous-equation, homogeneous-spaces

I got the task calculate the homogeneous representation of the line passing through the points (-4, 0) and (−2, 2) and to visualize the situation by drawing the lines and points in a 2D cartesian coordinate system.

I am getting confused between the homogeneous representation and the euclidean one...
How should I calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solve the two equations (dot product of the two points and the generic form of homogeneous line):
u*-4 + v*0 + g*1 = 0
u*-2 + v*2 + g*1 = 0

to get the relation between the three parameters of the representation:
u = - v
4v = -g

Then you can pick a value for say g:
g = 1
v = -1/4
u = 1/4

You can confirm this particular homogeneous line passes through the two point by calculating the dot products.

Comment: thanks you for your help!